# how to get IP addresses of the network connected pcs in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am Collecting newtowrk informations. from msdn i got few apis and which are working successfully. I want to collect all IP addresses of the network connected pcs. till now this is output which i get. i dont implement any API/Function for IP Address. Can anyone help.

Platform: 500
  Name:     GSI1
  Version:  6.2
  Type:     69639
  IP Address:

Platform: 500
  Name:     HELLO-PC
  Version:  6.1
  Type:     69635
  IP Address:

Platform: 500
  Name:     SCP
  Version:  6.3
  Type:     331779
  IP Address:

Platform: 500
  Name:     SCP-PC
  Version:  6.1
  Type:     200711
  IP Address:

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to retrive 10 IP addresses:

```
#include <winsock2.h>

// Add 'ws2_32.lib' to your linker options

WSADATA WSAData;

// Initialize winsock dll
if(::WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 0), &WSAData))
{
  // Error handling
}

// Get local host name
char szHostName[128] = "";

if(::gethostname(szHostName, sizeof(szHostName)))
{
  // Error handling -> call 'WSAGetLastError()'
}

// Get local IP addresses
struct sockaddr_in SocketAddress;
struct hostent     *pHost        = 0;

pHost = ::gethostbyname(szHostName);
if(!pHost)
{
  // Error handling -> call 'WSAGetLastError()'
}

char aszIPAddresses[10][16]; // maximum of ten IP addresses

for(int iCnt = 0; ((pHost->h_addr_list[iCnt]) && (iCnt < 10)); ++iCnt)
{


memcpy(&SocketAddress.sin_addr, pHost->h_addr_list[iCnt], pHost->h_length);
  strcpy(aszIPAddresses[iCnt], inet_ntoa(SocketAddress.sin_addr));
}

// Cleanup
WSACleanup();
```

You can find other examples [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/Q129/3/15.asp&NoWebContent=1).